# testing with selenium

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm a complete selenium newbie. Where should I start if I want to learn how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Selenium in two different ways:

1. [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) - Great at scripting tests that manipulate a large amount of data to hit or insert into a website because you can manipulate the Selenium commands from a real programming language (I used Ruby).
2. [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) - Excellent at making quick scripts to demonstrate problems and single path execution of a website.  The Firefox plugin integration is excellent and easy to use.  Non-developers can even create and submit scripts to demonstrate problems.

Pick one of the two ways and write a script to do something routine on the web (check for latest Hockey scores from NHL.com, etc).  After you have that super-simple script running, try something more complex.

Answer (score 3):

Download the firefox plugin to begin. You can record, replay some tests. There are some video tutorials.

Look at this [intro](http://www.scribd.com/doc/10154245/Selenium-Ide-Tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

You can get this book **Selenium 2 Testing Tools Beginner’s Guide**.
Really helpful book, especially for a newbie. I had a good experience, learning Selenium with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start from an overview [automated web testing with selenium](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3901353/automated-web-testing-with-selenium) presentation on scribd

Answer (score 2):

Better idea, to start selenium IDE, which is record and playback method like other tools.

Once familiar, then can start using selenium RC, Grid, Webdriver.

Selenium IDE is firefox extension. 
more help http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what you want to do with Selenium.

I definitely recommend getting Selenium IDE if you don't know what you're doing because it does most things automatically and gives you an intro to how you would use Selenium Remote Control.

Selenium Remote Control lets you use Selenium from your favourite language. From there it depends on what language you want to use for where you get help. I use Java/JUnit and I just use google/documentation/stackoverflow whenever there's something I'm not sure how to do and that Selenium IDE won't tell me how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the other suggestions on this page, one of the most useful sites I've used to get up to speed with Selenium was this one: [Selenium Training from theautomatedtester.com](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/selenium_training.htm)

He covers

- **Record & Playback**,
- **Javascript & Variables**,
- **XPaths**,
- **Regular Expressions** and more;

However, I think I only needed those first few ones.

Also, there are many extensions/addons/plug-ins for Selenium IDE, so be sure to check for any of those if you get stuck in some way.

For example, I thought I needed to start using the Selenium Remote Control (and code in C#) because I wanted to create tests with logical flows and loops...but there is a plug-in for incorporating that in the IDE ([goto & while loops extension](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html)), so I didn't need to!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Where to start?

Go to: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/

Read the docs from the beginning to the end.

Estimated time 8 hours.